# Android ウィジェットの ID 命名ポリシー

Tags: android

Android アクティビティ上のウィジェットに付ける ID はどのように命名するのが一般的でしょうか。

SDK 付属の ApiDemos 等を眺めた限りでは、例えば同じボタンでも、以下のように、「btn_…」「…_button」「(動詞のみ)」など、特に一貫性が無いようです。唯一の共通点はスネークケースであるということでしょうか。

```
<Button android:id="@+id/toggle_home_as_up" …
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_add_tab" …
<Button android:id="@+id/one_shot" …
<Button android:id="@+id/progress_button" …
```

公式でなくとも良いので、何かしらガイドライン等あると嬉しいのですが、良い情報があれば教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 参考になりそうなものに、 [Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) がありましたが、 そのIDの命名ルールには、何の言及もありませんねぇ…

Answer (score 2):

以下、回答しましたが、適当な回答ですみません。
予め断ると、コンセンサスを得やすく、上司が即了承するような
権威あるコーディングスタイルはなかったです。

本家で同様の質問があったので流し読みしたのですが、2011年の時点では公式のルールはありませんでした。
[Are there conventions on how to name resources?(リソースの命名規則はありますか？)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165582/are-there-conventions-on-how-to-name-resources)

上記質問から、確実に決まっているルールをサルベージしますと
・xmlのファイルネームは必ずa-zの小文字、0-9、あるいは「_」のどれか
 →ウィジェットID名も同様
・スネークケース(`_`で単語と単語が別れていること)
・iconのprefixは[決まっている](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

...ぐらいでした。
あとは、回答にあった[デザイナーのためのAndroidチートシート](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#naming-conventions-for-drawables)によれば、
drawableのprefixもSDKルールがあるらしいですけど。。。

個人的な意見を申し上げれば、
javaのコーディングスタイル[(例えばGoogleとか)](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.2-specific-identifier-names)なら探せばあるので、
キャメルケース⇆スネークケースの相互変換を意識して
ウィジェットのIDをそのままメソッドにしても英語警察を呼ばれないようにすることを
気をつけています。

以上、よろしく御願いいたします。